# Circular view path : would dispatch back to the current handler URL again. Check your ViewResolver setup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, circular-reference

I am learning Spring Boot and working through lessons. Pardon my newbieness. I have searched for this error, and tried suggestions I've found, which havent worked for me, so am posting the question. I hope someone can help me please.

This is a really simple application at the moment, I'm just trying to bring up courses.html when I use http://localhost:8080/  or http://localhost:8080/courses

I have a courses.html file located in the folder src/main/resources/templates

This is the resultant error:

```
2018-06-04 15:51:59.928 ERROR 3156 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Circular view path [courses]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/courses] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause
```

I have this code in my controller:

```
@Controller
public class CourseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String rootPath() {
        return "courses";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="courses")
    public String courses (ModelMap model) {
        return "courses";
    }

}
```

And this is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.proffesso.videos</groupId>
    <artifactId>CourseCreation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CourseCreation</name>
    <description>CourseCreation project using Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

One suggestion I read said to change the Spring Boot starter dependency from

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My POM file had both of those dependencies generated in it, and if I remove the spring-boot-starter-web one, then I get errors on @Controller and @RequestMapping

Comment: Without digging to deep, I see one thing: The second mapping should/could be "/courses". By the way, you can add different mappings to the same method, e.g. value={"/", "/course"}.

Comment: Thanks, had already tried that. Same error

Comment: I changed the version to 
<version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
instead of <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version> in the POM file, and updated my Maven. 

It works now.

Comment: Did you already tried 2.0.1?

Answer (score -2):

Error :
Would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/.../...] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view)

Solution:
Changed @Controller to @RestController.

Comment: That isn't a solution, at least not to this problem. This returns the string as is and doesn't render the view. So it doesn't actually solve anything.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).